# JDeveloper Heap Out of Memory

Tags: java, heap-memory, jdeveloper

I am getting the following error when I open a particular project in JDeveloper

```
Uncaught exception
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
  j.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
  j.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
  j.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
  j.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:224)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.getFullMessage(SVNErrorMessage.java:257)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:58)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNAdminAreaFactory.open(SVNAdminAreaFactory.java:163)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.doOpen(SVNWCAccess.java:364)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:272)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.open(SVNWCAccess.java:265)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.admin.SVNWCAccess.openAnchor(SVNWCAccess.java:145)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:320)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:296)
  org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:278)
  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:480)
  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.svnkit.SvnKitClientAdapter.getStatus(SvnKitClientAdapter.java:141)
  org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getStatus(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:466)
  o.ji.vcs.svn.SVNURLInfoCacheSimpleStrategy.getURLInfo(SVNURLInfoCacheSimpleStrategy.java:79)
  o.ji.vcs.svn.SVNURLInfoCache.getLastChangedRevision(SVNURLInfoCache.java:69)
  o.ji.vcs.svn.SVNOverlayProducer.createTooltip(SVNOverlayProducer.java:240)
  o.ji.vcs.svn.SVNOverlayProducer.getDecoratedOverlay(SVNOverlayProducer.java:144)
  o.ji.vcs.svn.SVNOverlayProducer.produceOverlay(SVNOverlayProducer.java:113)
  o.j.vcs.spi.VCSOverlayItemProducer.produceOverlays(VCSOverlayItemProducer.java:83)
  o.j.vcs.spi.VCSOverlayItemProducer.getOverlayItems(VCSOverlayItemProducer.java:65)
  o.j.vcs.spi.VCSNodeOverlayTracker.getOverlays(VCSNodeOverlayTracker.java:288)
  o.i.explorer.IconOverlayTracker.processPendingNodes(IconOverlayTracker.java:574)
  o.i.explorer.IconOverlayTracker.access$1400(IconOverlayTracker.java:69)
  o.i.explorer.IconOverlayTracker$7.run(IconOverlayTracker.java:487)
  j.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
  j.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

I have updated the jdev.conf file to include the following, but still receive the error:

```
AddVMOption  -XX:MaxPermSize=512M
AddVMOption -Xmx512M
AddVMOption -Xms512M
```

Furthermore, this project opens just fine without issue on a colleague's computer, where the jdev.conf file **-XX:MaxPermSize=512M** switch is set to 256M and the other 2 switches are not present.

I've spent the afternoon playing with different settings, trying to discover the difference, and I am left stumped. Is there something I'm missing? When I try to bump the setting to higher memory limits, JDeveloper fails to start the Java machine (I suspect that is related to memory allocated to Java itself), though it shouldn't be necessary, as the app works fine on my coworker's computer with half the memory allocated to JDeveloper.

Comment: `j.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity` seems like the stringbuilder is taking up too much memory, are you sure you tested it on your coworkers pc with the exact same settings?

Comment: Well, I thought I did - I'll have to look again. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egh. Simple, REALLY obvious solution that we just somehow overlooked. He is running an older version of JDeveloper. Installed that version, everything works.

Comment: What version of JDeveloper were you running, and which version did you switch back to?

Comment: Was running 11.1.1.3 - switched back to 10.1.3.5.

Comment: This isn't a solution to your problem. It's simply a workaround. :/ I intentionally switched to a newer version. So what now?!

Comment: @CodeNewbie No - it's the solution to my problem. I was using the wrong version of JDeveloper. Using the correct version fixed my issue. JDeveloper should offer the option to update the project file format. I have no explanation as for why it did not do so in my case.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and it get resolved with the help of below link :

[Fixing java.lang.OutOfMemory Java Heap Space error in JDeveloper](https://vikkiandtheweb.wordpress.com/2012/08/27/fixing-java-lang-outofmemory-java-heap-space-error-in-jdeveloper/)

Beside changing the configration fieles (jdev.conf and ide.conf) to have the commands

**JDEV.CONF**

AddVMOption -XX:MaxPermSize=256M

**IDE.CONF**

AddVMOption -Xmx768M
AddVMOption -Xms256M

See also this link:
[Jdeveloper throwing Out of Heap Space error with SVN](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2349486?tstart=0)

Beside, stop versioning option for Jdeverlper as follow:
In JDeveloper -> Choose Versioning menu -> Choose Configure -> Uncheck “Versioning support for Subversion”

> You can use some standalone SVN clients such as TortoiseSVN for
>   versioning

Comment: Just using tortoisesvn and disabling Versioning is the best method